# Refactor ruby each-code

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails

```
def users_list  
  html = ''  
  self.users.each do |user|  
    html << user.link_avatar_tag  
  end  
  html.html_safe  
end
```

I feel that it is possible to write shorter.

Is it possible get rid of the temporary variable(html)?

Comment: What class is user? `html_safe` is no standard method for String - What gems are you using? Or in short: Can you provide a MWE? And to answer: It looks ok for me.

Comment: Main topic of my question:

Is it possible get rid of the temporary variable(html)?

Comment: I'll tag this rails, that's where `html_safe` comes from.

Comment: one question about `self.users`, is this a model? a helper?

Comment: This is TaskDecorator.  
Task has_and_belongs_to_many :users  
https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Comment: @Fant: ok, I was unsure because you have `self` (not in helpers) but used `html_safe` (not in models). You can drop the `self` then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `map` (don't use `each` to accumulate. Check [this page about functional programming](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming)):

```
def users_list  
  users.map(&:link_avatar_get).join.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I change code a bit & that works:  
   
    self.users.map(&:link_avatar_tag).join.html_safe

Comment: mmm, yes, you are right, here `safe_join` is not necessary, edited.